# Формула для расчета количества товара

Tags: формулы

Добрый день!
Всю голову сломал, не могу составить формулу для расчета нужного кол-ва товара для коррекции.
Суть в следующем: есть два вида товаров - штучные и коробочные. Продаваться могут и те, и другие. Если оприходован штучный товар, то коробочный будет уходить в "-", если принимался коробочный, то у штучного будет отрицательный остаток.
Например, сок "Я" в коробке по 6 штук имеет артикул 111000. Одна пачка этого же сока имеет артикул 222000. Продалось 6 пачек сока, соответственно, остаток по артикулу 222000 будет "-5", а артикула 111000 останется неизменным.
Нужна формула, которая бы проставляла верные количества при коррекции товара, т.е. артикул 111000 скорректировала на "-1", а артикул 222000 на "+6".
К слову, таких товаров около 1500 артикулов, кратность упаковки везде разная (пиво, лимонады, вода и т.п.), поэтому вручную искать кол-во для коррекции очень проблематично.
За основу взят файл EXCEL, где напротив кода каждого штучного артикула прописан код коробочного товара.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас фактически одна и та же номенклатура имеет разные артикулы, то вам придется делать комплектацию/разукомплектацию номенклатуры в соответствии с расходами под каждое движение.

Правильно (удобно, если хотите) учитывать такие позиции как одну номенклатуру с разными единицами измерения, для которых прописывается кратность. У каждой номенклатуры есть базовая единица измерения (как правило, самая мелкая. например, штуки), в которой учитываются любые движения. При движении в других единицах измерения должен осуществляться автоматический пересчет в базовую единицу измерения.

То, что прописано в Excel'е это хорошо, надо теперь это учесть в вашей системе.

Использование нескольких артикулов (штрих-кодов) оправдано и со всех сторон и верно и удобно, однако эти упаковки различны могут быть только для кладовщиков и логистики, в складском (и бух) учете номенклатура должна быть одна.